# How to use an external NGINX server to route to Synology services?

Tags: dns, proxy, nas, nginx

First, I apologize if this isn't the right forum as this is somewhat of a networking question.

To give a brief explanation of what I want to achieve is basically have the services or apps provided by Synology be accessible via a simple URL without port numbers. I have a dedicated IP address, so I don't have to worry about setting up DDNS.

I thought all I would need to do is set up a very small NGINX server that would take in port 80/443 (SSL by Lets Encrypt and the primary domain is on Cloudflare. The NAS would be a subdomain).

This is what my NGINX server code looks like:

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    listen [::]:443 ssl;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/nas.mydomain.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/nas.mydomain.com/privkey.pem;

    root /var/www/nas/html;
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name nas.mydomain.com;

    location / {
       proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
       proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
       proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
       proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

       proxy_pass          https://EXTERNALIP:5001;
    }
}
```

However, it gives a 302 Bad Gateway error. Just playing around, I changed "proxy_pass" to be a Google Search Result, and instead, when I go to the FQDN, Google gives me a 404 error:

"404. That’s an error.

The requested URL /search was not found on this server. That’s all we know."

If there's a better way to handle this then I'm open to any and all suggestions. I'm not tied to using NGINX.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you confirmed that whatever services you're accessing are available via `https://EXTERNALIP:5001` from outside your local network (e.g. from your cellphone browser on its data plan, not Wifi) without Nginx?

Comment: Yea @Anaksunaman, I've been able to access them using my cell or if I'm connected via VPN. I'm wondering two things at this point: Is the port an issue with Cloudflare? Do I have to do anything special for Synology to "accept" a proxy URL?